# Steps to safely upgrade NodeJS Version

Tags: node.js

I have a project running with Node14 and want to upgrade it to `Node18.16`.
I want some advice from people that have already done this kid of upgrade about the steps necessary to safely upgrade NodeJS version.

I could think about some things like:

- Change local nodeJS version using nvm and test the project, check for errors/inconsistencies.
- Upgrade all dependencies running `npm outdated` then updating to the `Wanted` version. Is that right/enough?

Anything else we should always pay attention in this scenario?
Thanks!

Comment: You can test running the app using different node version with docker